# Borg backup - Reducing the size allocation of the backup data

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

I'm migrating from rdiff-backup to borgbackup and was wondering if it possible to reduce the size allocation of the backup data.
Looking in the data folder shows that files are maxed out at 500 MB.
Would it be possible to reduce that size down to 200MB? I know that this means I will have more files and the size of the backup may be slightly larger

The reason is that I'm syncing the borg repo to AWS s3 and my internet connection is rather slow compared to the size of the backup (160 GB) and it is not extremely stable. A dropped connection would mean that aws sync would have re upload up to 500 MB. Smaller files would reduces this problem

Thanks

Andy